# Wordpress store the_date() in a array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have this code in a foreach loop:

```
<?php $current_date[] = the_date('F Y'); ?>
```

What Im trying to do is gather all the dates into an array

but when I print_r my array, nothing appears...how would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_date`is an echo, use

```
<?php $current_date[] = the_date('F Y', '','', false); ?>
```

the `false` turns the echo off.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date

or as Pekka has it `get_the_date('F Y');`